# Converter uma Query com uma SubQuery para uma Query com um Join

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, query, otimização

Eu estou tentando otimizar uma `Query` que o sistema que eu estou trabalhando faz que tem uma `SubQuery` dentro, só que esta `SubQuery` esta referenciando uma outra tabela que tem relação com a tabela principal e pelo o que eu andei pesquisando talvez se a `Query` usasse o `Join` em vez de uma `SubQuery` seria mais rapido, a `Query` é esta:

```
SELECT COUNT(v.id_voto) FROM radar.rad_voto AS v
    WHERE (
        SELECT COUNT(vi.id_votoitem) FROM radar.rad_votoitem AS vi
            WHERE (
                vi.id_alternativa IN (1068, 1061)
            ) AND vi.id_voto = v.id_voto
    ) = 2;
```

Minha tentativa de conversão para `Join` falha:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM radar.rad_voto AS v
    JOIN radar.rad_votoitem AS vi ON vi.id_voto = v.id_voto
        WHERE (
            (vi.id_alternativa IN (1068, 1061)) AND vi.id_voto = v.id_voto
        );
```

O esquema das duas tabelas é esse:
[image: Tabela 1]
[image: Tabela 2]

Alguem poderia me dar uma luz?

(Obs: Não tenho muita experiencia em SQL, sei o basico para sobreviver)

Edit 1: O que eu estou querendo fazer é contar a quantidade de vezes que na tabela `rad_votoitem` tenha duas linhas com dois `id_alternativa` diferentes (com valor que eu vou especificar, aqueles la são meramente para exemplificar) e essas duas linhas tenham o mesmo `id_voto`

Comment: Sem muito tempo para poder explorar, mas creio que você possa usar a clásula `HAVING` do SQL para fazer esse filtro.

Comment: Explique melhor o que você quer contar. Pelo menos isto: AND vi.id_voto = v.id_voto você não precisa pois já está na condição de junção.

Comment: @anonimo Estou querendo contar a quantidade de vezes que na tabela `rad_votoitem` tenha duas linhas com dois `id_alternativa` diferentes (com valor que eu vou expecificar, usei aqueles ali meramente para exemplificar) e essas duas linhas tenham o mesmo `id_voto`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado de que forma eu poderia usar para obter o meu resultado desejado? Pode exemplificar?

Comment: Mas você precisa de mais algum dado da tabela rad_voto ou a contagem/seleção é toda feita na tabela rad_votoitem?

Comment: @anonimo não sei se entendi bem sua pergunta mas oq eu quero é só contar quantas vezes q na tabela `rad_votoitem` tem duas linhas com `id_alternativa` distintos e `id_voto` iguais

Answer (score 1):

Se você só precisa dos dados de rad_votoitem tente:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT id_voto) FROM rad_votoitem
WHERE id_alternativa IN (1068, 1061)
GROUP BY id_voto
HAVING count(id_voto) > 1;
```

Comment: Opa mano @anonimo, primeiramente muito obrigado pela sua resposta, seu `SQL` funcionou em partes, o problema dele é q ele esta me retornando uma coluna ("count") com a quantidade de linhas sendo o resultado da contagem de votos (que é oq eu quero) e cada linha com o número "1", eu contornei isso pegando esses dados como uma lista/array de números e retornando o tamanho dessa lista/array, funcionou só que teria uma forma de retornar o tamanho dessa lista direto pelo `SQL`?

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, boa tarde,

```
select
    count(v.id_voto)
from rad_voto v
    left join
rad_votoitem vi on v.id_voto = vi.id_voto
where vi.id_alternativa IN (1068, 1061)
group by vi.id_alternativa
having count(v.id_voto) = 2
```

Acredito que isso te atenderia. Mas cuidado com o HAVING, porque ele é processado após o retorno da consulta. Ele funciona como se fosse um último filtro, depois de tudo ter sido filtrado inicialmente.

Comment: Opa amigo @PauloAfonsoLimaGatti, primeiramente vlw pela resposta, infelizmente este SQL não funcionou, na verdade ele não retornou nada, não entendi o pq mas foi como se ele tivesse retornado null ou algo assim

Comment: como eu disse num comentário, o que eu estou querendo fazer é contar a quantidade de vezes que na tabela `rad_votoitem` tenha duas linhas com dois `id_alternativa` diferentes (com valor que eu vou especificar, usei aqueles la são meramente para exemplificar) e essas duas linhas tenham o mesmo `id_voto`